# Populate Data from a column and populate every 4th cell with data in sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to take data from a column "C4:C2048" and populate the first and every 4th cell in the adjacent column "D:D" with the values in the order they are in from column C.

I've tried variants on =IF(MOD(CELL("row",C5),5)=0,C5,"") but could not get it to be a draggable formula (so I do not have to spend weeks writing specific formula to get down to row 2048 or beyond (!!).  These serials will be scanned onto the excel workbook with a barcode scanner, and "return" will be pressed to populate column C with the row of serial numbers.

Can anyone help me out please??

Update 1:

Here is an example of what I need:

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3na4.jpg)

The data in column C is barcode scanned in, needs to output with the spacing in column D (every 4 rows).  Thanks again!

Comment: say you have this list in C4:C10 `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, are you trying to return `1,4,5,8,9` or `1,5,9` or `1,5,6,10` or `1,4,8`? Please provide a sample list and the expected output. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This, assuming set up as in screenshot?

```
=INDEX(C:C,ROW()*4)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. And to start from any row in col D, `ROW(A1)`

Comment: Updated my post, need every data point in column C, and for it to report every 4th column in D.

Comment: This is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(a1);4)=0;C1;"")
```

In column D that formula will give you what you asked for
Assuming your data starts in Row 1. If it starts in a different row. replace A1 and C1 respectively in the formula with the row number you start with.